# Scheduling a build script at a specific time from cruise control

Tags: cruisecontrol

I've been trying for a few weeks to run an ant script at a specific time each week to deploy a war file across many servers thats generated by cruise control from our SVN check-ins. The war file builds fine at every check in, but I cant seem to get the deploy script to automate.

I've tried something like this in config.xml :

```
<project name="deploy" requireModification = "false">

    <listeners>
      <currentbuildstatuslistener
          file="logs/Adeploy/status.txt"/>
    </listeners>

<compound includeTriggerChanges="false">
        <triggers>
     <scheduleTrigger time="15:28" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Scheduled">
         <weekDays>
            <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay>
         </weekDays>
    </scheduleTrigger>
    </triggers>
</compound>

<schedule>
                <ant buildfile = "deploy.xml" useLogger = "true"/>
    </schedule>
```

And this without any triggers:

```
 <schedule>
            <ant day = "Thursday" time = "1552" buildfile = "call-Auto-Deploy.xml" useLogger = "true"/>
</schedule>
```

But niether seems to be running. Is there something I'm missing from my Project config?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the clock on the server I was using was really off, this worked:

```
 <schedule>
            <ant day = "Thursday" time = "1552" buildfile = "call-Auto-Deploy.xml" useLogger = "true"/>
</schedule>
```